Split string by a word, unless
I want to split the sentences with "for", unless "all for" occurs in the sentence. It almost works, but for some reason one letter "s" is missing. What's wrong?
$arr = 'It is all for you','It is for you'
$arr | % {$_ -split '[^all] for'}



I just found solution:
$arr = 'It is all for you','It is for you'
$arr | % {$_ -split '(?<!all) for'}


Nice, though $arr -split '(?<!all) for' will do.

The regular expression [^all] does mean not (^) any occurrence of any of the letters, a,l or l.
A shorter way to get the same is [^al].
But you want to match all, so you should add a +, which means 1 or more occurrence of these letters.
$arr = 'It is all for you','It is for you'
$arr | % {$_ -split '[^al]+ for'}

output:
It is all for you

 you

But please note that a type like this will produce the same result:
'It is lal for you','It is for you' | % {$_ -split '[^al]+ for'}

EDIT: To match all for OR for you can do:
$arr = 'It is all for you','It is for you'
$arr | % {$_ -split 'all for|for'}

output:
It is 
 you
It is
 you

Or, when relying on powershell: $arr | % {$_ -split 'all for'} | % {$_ -split 'for'}
EDIT2:  Keeping It is all for you
$arr = 'It is all for you','It is for you'
$arr | % {$_ -split '^(It is all for you)|for'}

output:

It is all for you

It is
 you


Thanks for the clarification, you're right, but the question remains open. I need as a result "It is ... you"

Updated the answer.

No, unfortunately :), I need to keep the first sentence "It is all for you"
